# C, Multi-Dimensional Arrays Exercise

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

My understanding of a 2d array is wrong. So I'll approach this question another way. Say I have the following variables.

```
int student_id[10], course_id[5];

int student_course[10][2];
```

There can only be 10 students. There can only be 5 courses. A student can only take 2 courses.

```
/*prompt user for student id*/

/*
say that the value for: 
student_id[0]=123
*/

/*prompt user for course id*/

/*
say that the value for:
course_id[0]=101
course_id[1]=102
course_id[2]=103
course_id[3]=104
course_id[4]=105
*/
```

What I want to print out is the
`student_course[value_of_student_id][value_of_course_id]`.

So I thought of doing it this way:

```
int student_id[10], course_id[5], student_course[10][2]

int i, j, k;

for(i=0; i<10;i++){
    for(j=0; j<5; j++){

        /*prompt user for student id*/
        printf("Enter User ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &student_id);

        /*prompt user for course id*/
        printf("Enter Course ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &course_id);

        for(k=0; k<2; k++){
            student_course[i][j]=student_course[i][k];
        }

    }
}
```

If this is the wrong way, what is the correct way to get the results I want? A 3 dimensional array perhaps? I might not be ready for that yet.

Comment: Please add more comments to your code because I really don't get the sense

Comment: Think of a 2D array simply as a single dimension array and every spot in the array is another separate array.

Comment: "What I want to print out is the student_course[value of student_id][value of course_id]."

You can't do this because the "value of course_id" has 5 possibilities, ranging from 101 to 105, whilst you've declared the inner array to be of length 2.

Comment: I cant get how are you taking the input. Are you taking student_id and course_id pair every time?

Comment: so you want to map student_id against the current course_id (guess at the most 2 courses?) he has enrolled into?

Comment: It would seem you're on the verge of using your `[10][2]` array as an index table, where the values stored therein are indexes to your course array. If that is the case, the 2D array being used has little to do with the actual functional part of this exercise, but I can certainly see why it is confusing to try and meld the two in one's gray matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this instead

```
typedef struct
{
  int student_id;
  int course_id[2];
} Student

Student Students[10];
```

then initialize the array with the student_id's and what courses he is attending

Comment: I thought I understood Claptraps answer but I did not. If I was trying to print on screen the courses that Students[0] is taking. How would I go on and do it? I get errors when i try to print only Students[0].

Comment: @user2816227 to print the courses that Students[0] is taking, you would write something like `printf( "id:%d, courses:%d,%d\n", Students[0].student_id, Students[0].course_id[0], Students[0].course_id[1] );`