# C Programming, Structs and Multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am given an exercise that I can't seem to understand. I am almost done with my assignment but I'm stuck on this function.

Limitations:
There can only be 10 unique student ID's.
There are 5 subject area of study.
An a student can only take 2 subjects.

My struct.h look like this:

```
typedef struct student_info{
  int student_id;
  int course_id[2];
  }student;
```

In main.c

```
student info[10];
```

In func.c

Say I Prompt the user for a Student ID.

```
printf("Enter Student ID. ");
scanf("%d", &info->student[count_stud]->student_id;
```

User inputs 123

Then Prompt the user for a course ID.

```
printf("Enter Course ID. ");
scanf("%d", &info->student->course_id[count_cour];
```

User inputs 101

My problem lays with printing out a specific student_id and the course that student is taking. Also using a for loop I couldn't find a way to find a duplicate. I can find an id that was last inputted by the user but when I enter an id from 2 previous inputs it passes my if else statements.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &info[count_stud].student_id);`,`scanf("%d", &info[count_stud].course_id[count_cour]);`

Comment: Maybe if you showed these "if else" statements, and the code that seems to be giving you trouble, someone could help you.

Comment: `&info->student[count_stud]` is just wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys I copied it wrong.

Comment: My scantf is exactly as bluepixy suggested. I just want to be able to print out a student_id and the courses associated with that student_id. I don't know where to start. As for my duplicate error checking I will post in a different thread. One question at a time.

Comment: [Haven't we been here before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033207/c-multi-dimensional-arrays-exercise)? (not just a song from" Kilroy was Here").

Answer (score 1):

```
student info[10];
```

Here, `info` is `array` of `10 students` so you will have to read it with index.

```
for(int student_count = 0; student_count < 10; student_count ++)
{    
    printf("Enter Course ID 1 for student %d. ",student_count+1);
    scanf("%d", &info[student_count].course_id[0]);

    printf("Enter Course ID 2 for student %d. ",student_count+1);
    scanf("%d", &info[student_count].course_id[1]);
}
```